# How many ways to place 8 different books on 3 different shelves if order matters?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How can we place 8 different books on 3 different shelves if the order of the books on the shelves matters?

If the order didn't matter, then this problem would simply be a "stars and bars" problem. However, I don't know how to factor in the fact that the order of the books matters. I know that the number of ways to order n distinct objects is n!. Could someone at least give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Try to order the books first, which give you $8!$. Then you select two places (not necessarily distinct) to put your bars.

Comment: @k99731 This is a great way to think about it! Thank you!!

Comment: Are any of the shelves allowed to be empty?

Comment: @PeterJL It was not specified, so I am assuming that some of the shelves can be empty.